# %incMSE and %incnodepurity in python random forest

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there a python package or function that can calculate `%incMSE` and `%incNodePurity` in the same way that `randomForest` package in `R` calculates them thru `importance` function?

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) though I don't know enough about R to tell you if it has a variation on `%incMSE` or `%incnodepurity`. [This](http://www.slideshare.net/PyData/random-forests-r-vs-python-linda-uruchurtu) slide set seems to talk about it, though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `%incNodePurity` refers to the Gini feature importance; this is implemented under `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_`. According to the [original Random Forest paper](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#giniimp), this gives a "fast variable importance that is often very consistent with the permutation importance measure."

As far as I know, the permuation feature importance itself (`%incMSE`) is not implemented in scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks for this, so from what you were saying the `importances_` in `pyhton` is just the `%incNodePurity` from that of `R`'s `importance`. Am i right?